# Can Google Tag Manager events be triggered inside a PDF document?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a landing page website that consists of a button to download a PDF. The PDF is hosted on widen and has "links" inside it -- so once you download the document you can click on items inside the PDF to navigate around the PDF -- clicking on the table of contents sends you to that page of the PDF, etc.

Is it possible to add GTM triggers/events to something in a PDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can track the links from the pdf to your website by the UTMs in the URL but you cannot track the internal links to the pdf or insert the GTM in a pdf, because it is not loaded as if it were JavaScript.